# how does firefox check if a domain is a third-party domain?

Tags: firefox, dns

The firefox has an option to disable third-party cookies. So, how does the firefox check if a domain is a third-party domain? 
For example, is bbc.co.uk and bbci.co.uk the same domain, or for example, google.com, google.fr and google-analytics.com?

I am working on Web privacy, and I need to know what exactly is considered by a third-domain (in particular in firefox)?

EDIT:

How does the firefox browser gets the domain of the page we are visiting? For example, what is the domain of support.mozilla.org? According to their feature to gray out everything except the domain name, it seems that it is mozilla.org. Is it something it is returned by html document? Or the firefox gets it according to the visiting url?

Answer (score 0):

From [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Third-party_cookies):

> Cookies have a domain associated to them. If this domain is the same as the domain of the page you are on, the cookies is said to be a first-party cookie. If the domain is different, it is said to be a third-party cookie.

None of your examples are the same domain as any of the others.

Comment: Thank you on your answer. But, what about a domain and their subdomains? For example, you are visiting facebook.com, and imagine that there are images that lead to (for example) pixel.facebook.com. Is pixel.facebook.com the third-party domain for facebook (i.e a different domain)? Or if you are visiting developers.facebook.com and you have http requests to pixel.facebook.com?

Comment: Any conclusion?